# Spring context:property-placeholder for a boolean value

Tags: java, spring, boolean, applicationcontext

I am working on an application where I have two classes both implementing a common interface. So in time of bean declaration, I am going to mark one of them primary in my app-context.xml file. I can achieve this by simply declaring the primary bean like this:

```
<bean id="oracleImpl" class="com.me.dao.OracleImpl" primary="true">
</bean>
```

Now I don't want to hard code which of the beans is going to be the primary bean, rather want to read the true/false value from a properties file. So I went like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="oracleImpl" class="com.me.dao.OracleImpl" primary="${oracle.primary}">
</bean>

<bean id="pgsqlImpl" class="com.me.dao.PgsqlImpl" primary="${pgsql.primary}">
</bean>
```

The values of oracle.primary and pgsql.primary are defined in the file jdbc.properties along with other jdbc (non-boolean) properties.

But it doesn't work and says, "'${oracle.primary}' is not a valid value for 'boolean'"

I have a feeling it is something to do with the xsd validators. Browsing through this site and google gave me this much idea, but got no real solution. Can any body help?

Comment: What does the setter of the **primary** field in 'com.me.dao.OracleImpl' look like?

Comment: primary is not a field in 'com.me.dao.OracleImpl'. It is equivalent to spring annotation @primary. It is used to declare a bean the primary candidate for auto-wiring, when there is multiple beans of the same class.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work.

As of 3.2.5.RELEASE only the following bean definition elemets support property placeholder:

- parent name
- bean class name
- factory bean name
- factory method name
- scope
- property values
- indexed constructor arguments
- generic constructor arguments

See the [BeanDefinitionVisitor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinitionVisitor.java)'s `visitBeanDefinition` method for the details. This method is used by the [PlaceholderConfigurerSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java).

I would recommend you to create a feature request in the [spring issue management system](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

PS: if you create an issue please add a comment to the issues url.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you suggest any work around?

Comment: @waiting_for_peace I took closer look at the source code and I must say that there is no easy way to do it. The reason is that the `BeanDefinition`'s primary property is of type `boolean`. Thus the xml attributes value is already interpreted when the `BeanDefinition` object is created. Therefore you can not implement your own `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Maybe you can implement your own `DefaultListableBeanFactory` and override the method `isPrimary` or you will find a way to tell spring to use a special `BeanDefinitionParserDelegate` that you implemented. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your time :) Your tried really hard to assist me, but I am new to this so I think I will go with the hard coded way this time. Thanks again.